# Javascript veriable selector how to use as

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The title may have been wrong. because I don't know the exact definition of this question. I'm sorry for that.

I have 2 objects named user and customer.
I want to get the data in these objects. but variable names conflict

my code;

```
   const { loading, error, data } = user;
   const { loading, error, data } = customer;
```

i want to do

```
const { loading as userLoading, error as userError, data as userData} = user;
const { loading as customerLoading, error as customerError, data as customerData} = customer;
```

Comment: This is called a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assigning_to_new_variable_names)

Comment: @Thomas you are awesome. you helped me learn something new. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have your variables like this or similar:

```
const user = { loading: true, error: false, data: true }
const customer = { loading: false, error: true, data: false }
```

Do this to assign the values to your preferred names

```
const { loading: userLoading, error: userError, data: userData } = user;
const { loading: customerLoading, error: customerError, data: customerData } = customer;
```